# How do I configure a backend in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backend

I seem to be missing something fundamental. I added a backends.yaml file to the directory where my app lives in my development environment. This file contains the following:

```
backends:
- name: reporting
  class: B8
  options: dynamic public
```

I deployed and the admin console says I don't have any backends configured. I tried using appcfg.py like this:

```
appcfg.py backends ~/work/google/myappfolder list
```

and it says:

```
No backends configured for app: {my app name}.
```

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview) says:

```
appcfg backends <dir> list
Lists all the backends configured for the app specified in dir/app.yaml.
```

Is `app.yaml` a typo? Or is my problem that I should be putting something into app.yaml? I didn't find any mention of that anywhere else.

Also, some of the documentation says you have to start all backends manually, but other parts say that "dynamic" backends do not need be started from the command line -- they are started automatically. Which is it?

This was answered by alex in the comments. Here are the key take-aways:

1. You must do `appcfg.py backends dir update` to get things going
2. You must do that **again** every time you update your code (clicking the deploy button in the launcher program does not update your backends!)
3. That app.yaml in the docs is a typo
4. You do not need to start dynamic backends from the command line; they do start automatically
5. The logs are useless in debugging backend issues; do not assume a lack of information in the logs is indicative of anything
6. If giving multiple options, separate them with commas

Comment: I don't see you saying you did `appcfg backends <app_dir> update`. This should upload your backed code first, *before* you can actually `list` or do anything else on production servers.

Comment: Aha! Thanks. So now I'm getting an error, because it doesn't like options: dynamic public. But it also doesn't like having two options: lines. How do I specify more than one option?

Comment: Nevermind, figured out that I need to separate them with commas.

Comment: OK, so I've now got a backend appearing in my console, and when I hit it with a URL request, it is being started. (So that answers whether it is necessary to start it from the command line: no it is not.) However, when I hit the backend with a request, I get: Error: Server Error

The service you requested is not available yet.
Please try again in 30 seconds. (There is nothing in the log. Not the request, nor the error.)

Comment: Can it be that your backend code simply doesn't match the URL pattern you hit it with? Also, make sure you either respond with a 200-like code to /_ah/start|stop from your backend or don't handle those at all (404 is OK). It just might be App Engine thinks your backend isn't ready.

Comment: OK, I've got it working. The trouble, I think, was that I didn't realize that I need to do an "update" command every time I change my code. I'm used to just using the launcher to deploy, and I didn't realize that the launcher does not update backends.

Comment: Yeah, currently backends are just a special kind of app version. So, you basically need to sort of update two versions at a time when you work on code related to both frontend and backends. I think it'll change (for the better!) next year.

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually started the backend up via the command line?

```
 appcfg backends <dir> start <backend>
```

> Sets the backend state to START, allowing it to receive HTTP requests. Resident backends start immediately. **Dynamic backends do not start until the first user request arrives**. Has no effect if the backend was already started.

So yes, you do need to do that before it can serve even on dynamic instances as you have.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview#Commands

Also, did you pass `--backends` to enable backends support in `dev_appserver.py`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, and it gave me an error saying that the backend did not exist. And then I tried the list command, and you can see the output. So thanks for answering my second question, but I'm still stuck on my first one.

Comment: This is what it says...
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Starting backend: reporting
Backend 'reporting' has not been defined.
--- end server output ---

Comment: Also, in case it matters, this app is still on M/S and Python 2.5.

Comment: have you set the number of instances also? try adding "instances: 1" to your backend yaml

Comment: did you pass --backends to enable backends support in dev_appserver.py?

Comment: No, but why would I need to? dev_appserver is not even running. I'm trying to use backends in the real public app in google's cloud, not locally.

Comment: Beats me. I wouldn't even know how to trigger it, since the routing in the real cloud is triggered by cname trickery.

Comment: I mean, backends are supported on the local development server. Do they work for you there?